# How to migrate existing Hbase data to a new cluster

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs

I hava a Hbase Cluster storing more than 10TB data, now I have to migrate these data into a new cluster,how can I do this?

I know Hbase backup have full shutdown backup(Distcp) and Live Cluster Backup(Replication,Export and CopyTable).

In my case we can't tolerate a periodic full shutdown of our Hbase cluster, and I know Replication can't copy the history data, so this means we can just use Export or CopyTable?

---

I have two questions:

1.Should we use Export or CopyTable or others? why?

2.If we use Export or CopyTable, since the cluster is up ,there is a risk that edits could be missed in the copy process, how to avoid it?

Answer (score 1):

**CopyTable**

CopyTable will directly write the data into an existing HBase table. This can be done in the same cluster or a remote cluster.
Both clusters should be online in order to make this done.

**Export**

Export that is used to export the data of the HBase table to plain sequence files in the HDFS folder. A MapReduce job gets created which will call the HBase cluster to get the data from the specified table and write it to the HDFS folder.

I would prefer you to use copytable rather than export because MR jobs takes time.

Reference: [Dzone HBase](https://dzone.com/articles/hbase-a-hadoop-nosql-database-backup-process-expla)

Comment: thank you for your answer~ I know we can use CopyTable, but the reference guide says that "since the cluster is up ,there is a risk that edits could be missed in the copy process" , how to avoid it?

Answer (score 1):

given two clusters, ClusterA, ClusterB, a tablex needs migrating.

migrating tablex from CLuster A to Cluster B.

1. add replication peer '99' from A->B
2. on A shell, enable_table_replication 'tablex'
3. on A shell, disable_peer '99'
4. on A shell, snapshot 'tablex', 'tablex_snapshot'
5. on A machine, export snapshot， bin/hbase  org.apache.hadoop.hbase.snapshot.ExportSnapshot -snapshot 'tablex_snapshot' -copy-to hdfs://clusterB:8020/user/hbase -mappers 16
6. on B shell, restore_snapshot 'tablex_snapshot', 'tablex'
7. on A shell, enable_peer '99'

done.